# Can i develop an IOS mobile app using flutter on MAC, and work on android devices as well

Tags: flutter, dart

i am new to programming, but i have some App ideas that i would like to develop one day, recenetly i have checked alot of materials about flutter, but alot of articles were saying that i can't develop IOS mobile apps using windows PC, should have a MAC.

so my question is can i develop IOS mobile apps on MAC, but can work on android devices at the same time? or i need to have a PC for the android version & a MAC for the IOS version?

also is thier any other solutions for that? like using third party cross platforms mobile app frameworks like react native / ionic etc.? and if which of them can use flutter?

Answer (score 0):

> so my question is can i develop IOS mobile apps on MAC, but can work on android devices at the same time? or i need to have a PC for the android version & a MAC for the IOS version?

No, you don't need windows PC for running app in Android, macOS is sufficient.

> also is thier any other solutions for that? like using third party cross platforms mobile app frameworks like react native / ionic etc.? and if which of them can use flutter?

There could be, but I think you can use VM to run macOS on your windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac computer you can run your app on both devices at the same time. (ios and android) You can try it with real device or just simulator. What I did is I run ios on a simulator and android on a real device. It works perfectly fine

Yes there is, you can try react native. You can develop an ios app without a mac using expo - https://expo.io/ . But at the end of the development you will then need a real mac to upload it on appstore.

You can also try Virtual Machines like VMware. You can install a mac os on your windows computer using it. But the performance of it is not that great. The other solution is to try Hackintosh

Answer (score 0):

The two scenarios -

1) Mac - If you develop on Mac you can build and debug for both platforms without any trouble. Same flutter project can be opened in Android Studio (for Android) and Xcode (for iOS).

2) Windows - If you are using Windows then developing for Android isn't a problem as you can use Android Studio. But there is no straight forward way for iOS. It is possible though, you can follow [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667) article.